# Submission title for versions of JavaScript, regarding normalization for leaderboard scripts

Tags: discussion, answers

I've seen a few variations of submissions specifying the ECMAScript version of JavaScript, and this creates problems for leaderboard scripts since they end up being treated as different languages under the "by language" category.

Namely, for JavaScript ES5, I've seen:

## JavaScript

## ES5

## JavaScript ES5

ES6 and ES7:

## JavaScript ES6/7

## ES6/7

What should we title these submissions as, so that there's no more confusion for leaderboard scripts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Specifying the ES standard seems like a good idea to keep these separate in the leaderboards. Of course, it becomes a problem if the same ES standard is specified in different formats. So without any reason in particular, just to create *one* standard I propose using one of

### JavaScript

### JavaScript (ES6)

Depending on whether the answer works in all common ES versions or only in a specific one. Note that `ES5` should also be specified if your answer works *only* in ES5 (I don't know how backwards-compatible ES6 is). The plain version with `JavaScript` should be reserved for "version polyglots".

Of course, I wouldn't expect everyone to have seen this post, but those who have could always edit nonconforming answers if they see them and put a link to this answer in the edit summary.

Comment: I should probably clarify, when I said `JavaScript ES6/7` I didn't mean it literally, but rather I was shortening it to mean either `JavaScript ES6` or `JavaScript ES7` are two forms that I've seen.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Oh right... I guess I'll remove that.

Comment: Also, I am in complete agreement that we should keep versions different, I had no qualm with that, but like you, I agree that each version should have a normalized title. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear about that.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts No, you were clear about that, but I wanted to address it in the answer for completeness anyway.

Comment: I hope the day comes soon where the default for JavaScript would _be_ ES6 and that you'd have to specify an ES5-only answer...

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I'll clarify this, but you should also specify an ES5-only answer right now. Plain `JavaScript` should only be used if it works in all common JS versions.

Comment: Ah, I see. As in, "cross-browser"?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ As in cross-version (which at the moment is probably the same thing).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: JS should be done the same way as Python - specify the version unless it works with both 2 and 3.